# I am receiving could not find "htmlextra" reporter when i run it on my local (MAC OSX) neman html report generation

Tags: npm, report, command-line-interface, newman

I am receiving below message, when i run newman run command with parameter -r htmlextra. Where i have already installed htmlextra using -g (globally). But when i create a newman .js file i am able to execute. Please advice what might have went wrong.

```
newman: could not find "htmlextra" reporter
ensure that the reporter is installed in the same directory as newman
please install reporter using npm
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue resolved. By copying the newman-reporter-html, newman-reporter-htmlextra packages into the newman -> node_modules directory.

Ideally the modules has to been within the node_modules directory.

It was on mac os x. I hope similar is applicable to windows OS based machines.

Answer (score 2):

This could be fixed by installing `newman` and `newman-reporter-htmlextra` globally using the following command:

```bash
npm install -g newman newman-reporter-htmlextra
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed htmlextra reporter by npm install -g htmlextra then to generate report ideally you should use

newman run yourpostmancollection.json -r htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export pathToHtmlReportFile

after running this the report file should be generated on the given path

Answer (score 1):

If you are using node version manager try using node 10.

```
nvm use 10
npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra
newman run collection.json -r htmlextra
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have installed newman with npm i -g newman and html exporter with sudo or the other way around.

Make sure that if you install one package -g (global) then the other likewise, if 1 sudo then the other too